# Integrate with npm install

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, npm

What I am trying to do is when I do npm install for my app itself I need to check unused dependencies in package.json.

Is there any way to include npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package during npm install itself, so that I don't need to install it seprately see unused dependencies like this

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you add more information?

Comment: @Marty thanks for your reply I updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what you're trying to do, but I might be confused. Check out the "scripts" option for package.json. You can install depcheck-es6 as a dev dependency, and then do something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": "depcheck [directory] [arguments]"
}
```

Which would check your dependencies before you publish, it will also be run locally when you run `npm install` which I think accomplishes what you want.

Check out all the options in the [NPM Scripts Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)